# Nested class member variables not accessible. Linked list set up. issues with v, next and new

Tags: c++

I am having some problems with this linked list build and getting member functions to be able to access nested class variables.  They are all in the same scope, so?

```
class intLinkedList {
    public:
    class node {
        int v;
        node* next;
    };
    private:
        node* root;
        node* tail; 
        int pop;

    public:
    intLinkedList() {
        root = NULL;
        tail = NULL; 
        pop = 0; 
    }

    ~intLinkedList() {
        // dump all nodes
        clear();
    }

        int insert(int v) {
        node* new = new node;
        new->v = v;
        new->next = root;
        root = new;
        pop++;
        return(0);
    }
```

Here is the class and the nested class...
Any thoughts on why I can't access the variables from the nested class?

Comment: What does the compiler output? It's enough to read thoughtfully the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that class `node` is embedded inside class `intLinkedList` does not imply that the outer class is allowed to access the **private** members of its inner class. It means that outside the outer class, the inner class is not directly visible.

The quickest fix is to make the outer class a `friend class` of the inner class; like this:

```
#include  <cstddef>

class intLinkedList {
    public:
    class node {
        int v;
        node* next;
        friend class intLinkedList;  // HERE CHANGE
    };
    private:
        node* root;
        node* tail; 
        int pop;

    public:
    intLinkedList() {
        root = NULL;
        tail = NULL; 
        pop = 0; 
    }

    ~intLinkedList() {
        // dump all nodes
        //--clear();
    }

    int insert(int v) {
        node* newp = new node;  // USED NEWP AS "NEW" IS A KEYWORD
        newp->v = v;
        newp->next = root;
        root = newp;
        pop++;
        return(0);
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't realize that.  Thanks for your experienced look.

Answer (score 0):

By default all class members are private. The fact that the class is nested doesn't change this rule: intLinkedList::node::v is private.

Two simple solutions are: make the members public,

```
    class node {
    public:
        int v;
        node* next;
    };
```

or just make your node a `struct`:

```
    struct node {
        int v;
        node* next;
    };
```

In addition, have you compiled this code? The compiler shall produce an error on the variable `new` because this is a keyword.

Comment: yes, "new" should be anything other...like quiggley.  Please excuse my shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 straightforward options:
1: Declare the outer class as a friend in the nested class. This gives it access to all members within the nested class.

```
    class intLinkedList {
        public:
            class node {
                int v;
                node* next;
                friend class intLinkedList;
            };
            intLinkedList();
            ~intLinkedList();
            int insert(int v);

        private:
            node* root;
            node* tail; 
            int pop;
    };
```

2. If only the outer class will be using the nested class directly, then you can create a private struct within the outer class.

   ```
   class OuterClass
   {
   private:
       struct InnerClass
       {
           int var; //Everything here visible by default.
       };
   };
   ```

To improve readability in your header files only declare the functions, define them in the cpp file (see example 1).